# Why User and Session doesn't work when acessed from AppServiceProvider in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel-5

I'm using `AppServiceProvider` to pass data to all views, like I was told:

```
<?php namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use App\User;
use Session;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider {

    public function boot()
    {
        $userID = Session::get('userID');
        $user = User::find($userID);
        view()->share('user', $user);
    }

    public function register()
    {
        $this->app->bind(
            'Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Registrar',
            'App\Services\Registrar'
        );
    }
}
```

This causes no errors, however `$user` is `null` in my views. This same code to obtain `$user` works just fine when returned directly from a regular Controller. The views also work fine when $user is injected manually.

The next step was to create a new method in the User model:

```
public static function getSessionUser(){
    return self::find(Session::get('SteamID64'));
}
```

Again, this works just fine everywhere except at `AppServiceProvider`.

I'm open to any suggestion, even a different approach to pass `$user` to my views.

I don't understand what causes this and really need help with it. Thanks for your time!

Comment: Attempt to `dd()` something in either the boot and register function to make sure the ServiceProvider is ran.

Comment: I'm having a similar problem. I create a session value inside the boot method, and it's no accesible in the controllers. I am thinking that maybe the user is not identified yet at the AppServiceProvider stage. Also it seems that the session is not shared as the session id is different.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very experienced with Laravel but I suspect this service provider is just not being loaded. Have you added the provider to the ['providers' array in your config/app.php file](http://laravel.com/docs/master/providers#registering-providers)?